# sql different columns compare

Tags: sql, algorithm

I have a database table with six columns(column1,column2...column6). The data are ordered and none repeat. These are the data in the database table

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
--------------------------------------------
1       3       4       6       7       8
2       5       7       9       10      14
```

I want to write sql to compare the data, if I have the data which one different number in varied/shift position. These are the parameters in the sql select statement.

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
--------------------------------------------
2       3       4       6       7       8
3       4       6       7       8       9
1       2       4       6       7       8
```

I want to query out the row 1,3,4,6,7,8

More complex...two different numbers and three different numbers

Merry Christmas!!

The following sql is from my friend.

```
 data in table: Col1=10, Col2=11, Col3=12, Col4=13, Col5=26, Col6=28
  parameters: 10,11,12,18,26,28


 select * from 
 ( select id,Col1,Col2, Col3,Col4, Col5,Col6,
         ( (case when Col1=10 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col2=10 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col3=10 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col4=10 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col5=10 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col6=10 then 1 else 0 end)
         )
       +(  (case when Col1=11 then 1 else 0 end)  
          +(case when Col2=11 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col3=11 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col4=11 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col5=11 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col6=11 then 1 else 0 end)
        )
       +(  (case when Col1=12 then 1 else 0 end)  
          +(case when Col2=12 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col3=12 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col4=12 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col5=12 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col6=12 then 1 else 0 end)
        )
       +(  (case when Col1=18 then 1 else 0 end)  
          +(case when Col2=18 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col3=18 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col4=18 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col5=18 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col6=18 then 1 else 0 end)
        )
       +(  (case when Col1=26 then 1 else 0 end)  
          +(case when Col2=26 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col3=26 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col4=26 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col5=26 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col6=26 then 1 else 0 end)
        )
       +(  (case when Col1=28 then 1 else 0 end)  
          +(case when Col2=28 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col3=28 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col4=28 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col5=28 then 1 else 0 end) 
          +(case when Col6=28 then 1 else 0 end)
        ) as sub
       from [DBName1].[dbo].[nList] ) aa
       wheCole aa.sub>=5
```

Please give more comments and new answers!
Thanks for the reply !

Comment: what you tried till now?

Comment: What does "math the data" mean?

Comment: @Piyush 1. List all the possibles :(   2. contaminate the number into one column then  use math INTERSECT function. Can't find the function in sql.

Comment: @ScottHunter compare the data, if they are equal. sorry for the english, hope you get the meaning

Comment: What you are wanting is sometimes called "edit distance" when used on character strings.  I don't know of a builtin SQL function to do it, particulary on multiple columns.  You'll likely need to write your own code, probably best as a stored procedure/function.

Comment: just to clarify: you have TWO tables which you want to compare row-by-row and find all the rows in the first table that differs exactly in one (two, three) numbers from any row in the second table. right?

Comment: This almost sounds like a lottery database and you are looking for common combinations to play for future of most common repeated "sets".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of the solution (for SQL Server 2005 and above):

```
-- PREPARATIONS
create table #tbl1 (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 int);
create table #tbl2 (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 int);

insert into #tbl1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) values
(1,       3,       4,       6,       7,       8),
(2,       5,       7,       9,       10,      14);

insert into #tbl2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) values
(2,       3,       4,       6,       7,       8),
(3,       4,       6,       7,       8,       9),
(1,       2,       4,       6,       7,       8);
go

create function [dbo].[CompareDelimitedStrings] (@value1 varchar(max), @value2 varchar(max), @separator char(1))
returns int
as
begin
    declare @result int = 0;

    with r1 as
    (
        select value, cast(null as varchar(max)) [x], 0 [no] from (select rtrim(cast(@value1 as varchar(max))) [value]) as j
        union all
        select right(value, len(value)-case charindex(@separator, value) when 0 then len(value) else charindex(@separator, value) end) [value]
        , left(r.[value], case charindex(@separator, r.value) when 0 then len(r.value) else abs(charindex(@separator, r.[value])-1) end ) [x]
        , [no] + 1 [no]
        from r1 r where value > ''
    )
    , r2 as
    (
        select value, cast(null as varchar(max)) [x], 0 [no] from (select rtrim(cast(@value2 as varchar(max))) [value]) as j
        union all
        select right(value, len(value)-case charindex(@separator, value) when 0 then len(value) else charindex(@separator, value) end) [value]
        , left(r.[value], case charindex(@separator, r.value) when 0 then len(r.value) else abs(charindex(@separator, r.[value])-1) end ) [x]
        , [no] + 1 [no]
        from r2 r where value > ''
    )
    select @result = count(*)
    from (
        select x, [no] from r1 where x is not null
        intersect
        select x, [no] from r2 where x is not null
    ) as t

    return @result;
end
go

-- SOLUTION   
with [t1] as
(
    select *
    , replace(str(col1) + ',' + str(col2) + ',' + str(col3) + ',' + str(col4) + ',' + str(col5) + ',' + str(col6), ' ', '') [str]  
    from #tbl1
)
, [t2] as
(
    select *
    , replace(str(col1) + ',' + str(col2) + ',' + str(col3) + ',' + str(col4) + ',' + str(col5) + ',' + str(col6), ' ', '') [str]  
    from #tbl2
)
select distinct t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5, t1.col6
from t1
-- number 5 in this case means 5 intersections (or 1 difference).
-- you can change this number to 4 or 3 to find rows with 2 or 3 differences
join t2 on [dbo].[CompareDelimitedStrings] (t1.[str], t2.[str], ',') >= 5;

-- CLEANUP
drop table #tbl1;
drop table #tbl2;
drop function [dbo].[CompareDelimitedStrings];
```

Result:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
--------------------------------------------
1       3       4       6       7       8
```

Algorithm in a few words: joining these two tables on the next condition: intersection of the numbers in the rows must be greater or equal to 5 (for the case with 1 difference)

---

This is the **one-table-solution** (shows the matched pairs and intersections count)

```
-- PREPARATIONS
create table #tbl (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 int);

insert into #tbl (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) values
(1,       3,       4,       6,       7,       8),
(2,       5,       7,       9,       10,      14),
(2,       3,       4,       6,       7,       8),
(3,       4,       6,       7,       8,       9),
(1,       2,       4,       6,       7,       8);
go

create function [dbo].[CompareDelimitedStrings] (@value1 varchar(max), @value2 varchar(max), @separator char(1))
returns int
as
begin
    declare @result int = 0;

    with r1 as
    (
        select value, cast(null as varchar(max)) [x], 0 [no] from (select rtrim(cast(@value1 as varchar(max))) [value]) as j
        union all
        select right(value, len(value)-case charindex(@separator, value) when 0 then len(value) else charindex(@separator, value) end) [value]
        , left(r.[value], case charindex(@separator, r.value) when 0 then len(r.value) else abs(charindex(@separator, r.[value])-1) end ) [x]
        , [no] + 1 [no]
        from r1 r where value > ''
    )
    , r2 as
    (
        select value, cast(null as varchar(max)) [x], 0 [no] from (select rtrim(cast(@value2 as varchar(max))) [value]) as j
        union all
        select right(value, len(value)-case charindex(@separator, value) when 0 then len(value) else charindex(@separator, value) end) [value]
        , left(r.[value], case charindex(@separator, r.value) when 0 then len(r.value) else abs(charindex(@separator, r.[value])-1) end ) [x]
        , [no] + 1 [no]
        from r2 r where value > ''
    )
    select @result = count(*)
    from (
        select x, [no] from r1 where x is not null
        intersect
        select x, [no] from r2 where x is not null
    ) as t

    return @result;
end
go

-- SOLUTION   
with [t] as
(
    select *
    , replace(str(col1) + ',' + str(col2) + ',' + str(col3) + ',' + str(col4) + ',' + str(col5) + ',' + str(col6), ' ', '') [str]
    , row_number() over(order by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) [id]
    from #tbl
)
, cross_dedup as
(
    select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5, t1.col6
    , [dbo].[CompareDelimitedStrings] (t1.[str], t2.[str], ',') [intersections_count]
    -- ranking the cross-doubled pairs
    , row_number() over (partition by case when t1.id > t2.id then t1.id else t2.id end order by t1.id, t2.id) [rank]
    from t t1
    -- number 5 in this case means 5 intersections (or 1 difference).
    -- you can change this number to 4 or 3 to find rows with 2 or 3 differences
    join t t2 on [dbo].[CompareDelimitedStrings] (t1.[str], t2.[str], ',') >= 5
    and t1.id != t2.id
)
select distinct col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, [intersections_count] from cross_dedup where [rank] = 1;

-- CLEANUP
drop table #tbl;
drop function [dbo].[CompareDelimitedStrings];
```

Result:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    intersections_count
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1       2       4       6       7       8       5
1       3       4       6       7       8       5
```

Comment: I have one table, but I got your idea. Your answer works! thank you.

Comment: not at all. in case you have one table you can self-JOIN it on the same condition AND additional condition than rows are not the same (it perhaps forced you to add the row numbers).